# GStreamer pipeline broken

Tags: linux, terminal, gstreamer, pipeline, v4l2

I am not sure why this pipeline is breaking, I have gstreamer installed on linux from the websites exact instructions, any ideas?

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoscale ! video/x-raw, width=2592, height=600 ! autovideosink -v
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(3055): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 0:00:00.000093207
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

If I change it to:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert! videoscale ! video/x-raw, width=2592, height=600 ! autovideosink -v
```

it will work but why will it not work the other way?

Comment: If i change it to: gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert! videoscale ! video/x-raw, width=2592, height=600 ! autovideosink -v , it will work but why will it not work the other way?

Comment: Don't post this sort of information in a comment. Edit your question to show that alternative. Otherwise a pretty good first Q. Let me know you made that change, and we can delete these exteraneous comments (and I'll upvote your Q). Good luck.

Answer (score 12):

Your webcam transmits raw video output to whoever is listening to it. Adding `videoconvert` encodes the raw video to a codec that can be manipulated by the `videoscale` element and the end product of the manipulation to be understood by the `autovideosink` element.

So `gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert! videoscale ! video/x-raw, width=2592, height=600 ! autovideosink` is telling gstreamer to get the raw video from the camera, encode it into something that we understand, alter the video, and display it.

I really recommend that when you have doubts about an element, call `gst-inspect-1.0 <element name>` to see it's description and properties.

Comment: Really helpful common on using gst-inspect!

Comment: I have a similar problem but adding videoconvert did not solve it. In fact it generated another error (Failed to allocate required memory). What can be a solution?

Comment: @KansaiRobot can you share the pipeline you're running?